# JS - Insert element on the <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html, addition, innerhtml

I need to add a  tag with some Elements, but the innerHTML inserts  before appendChild.
My Js function:

```
function addFields(){
    var isbn_container = document.getElementById("isbn_container");
    isbn_container.innerHTML += "<div>";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "new-isbn-10[]";
    isbn_container.appendChild(input);

    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.type = "text";
    input2.name = "new-isbn-13[]";
    isbn_container.appendChild(input2);
    isbn_container.innerHTML += "<span onclick='deleted(this);'> delete</span>";
    isbn_container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    isbn_container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    isbn_container.after.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

The result:

```
<div></div>
<input type="text" name="new-isbn-10[]">
<input type="text" name="new-isbn-13[]">
<span onclick="deleted(this);"> delete</span>
<br><br>
```

But I want:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="new-isbn-10[]">
<input type="text" name="new-isbn-13[]">
<span onclick="deleted(this);"> delete</span>
<br><br>
</div>
```

Help me please.

Comment: Why aren't you creating the DIV using DOM methods too? Inserting "<div>" via innerHTML is invalid markup, so it will almost certainly be corrected to "<div></div>". Inserting "</div>" will probably be ignored, but again, you're into (undocumented, not standardised) error correction so anything could happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
function addFields(){
    var isbn_container = document.getElementById("isbn_container");
    isbn_container.innerHTML += "<div>";
```

Don't do that, it's invalid markup and completely unnecessary given the following line:

```
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "new-isbn-10[]";
    isbn_container.appendChild(input);
```

You want this inside the div, so don't do that, add it to the div:

```
    div.appendChild(input);
```

Same here:

```
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.type = "text";
    input2.name = "new-isbn-13[]";
    isbn_container.appendChild(input2);
```

Replace with:

```
    div.appendChild(input2);
```

Again, adding stuff to *isbn_container* doesn't put it in the div, so don't do this:

```
    isbn_container.innerHTML += "<span onclick='deleted(this);'> delete</span>";
    isbn_container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    isbn_container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Do this:

```
    div.innerHTML += "<span onclick='deleted(this);'> delete</span>";
    div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Now all that stuff is in the div, so you can now add the div to the document:

```
    isbn_container.appendChild(div);
}
```